# How do I update a view after ng-submit calls a factory function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

$scope.temp and $scope.description don't have values until ng-submit calls $scope.getWeather. I can log the values after submission, but can't update the view to display them. $scope.test is demonstrating that my view will only display "This is a DEFAULT value" and not update to "This is the NEW value" when $scope.getWeather is called. Thanks.

```
angular.module('forecastCtrl', ['weatherService'])
.controller('forecastController', function($http, $scope, Weather) {
    //var vm = this;

    $scope.test = 'This is a DEFAULT value';

    $scope.getWeather = function(postData) {

        Weather.get(postData)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.test = 'This is the NEW value';
                $scope.temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
                $scope.description = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text;
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    };

// THIS IS THE FORM
<form name="getWeatherForm" action="#" ng-submit="getWeather(postData)" class="small-10 large-6 small-centered large-centered columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
         <div class="small-9 columns">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Philadelphia, PA" ng-model="postData.city">
         </div>
         <div class="small-3 columns">
              <button type="submit" class="button postfix">Go</button>
         </div>
    </div> 
</form>


//THIS IS THE FACTORY
angular.module('weatherService', [])
.factory('Weather', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(location) {
            location = location.city;
            location = location.replace(/\s/g, '');
            // do error handling
            return $http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22'+location+'%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys');
        }
    }
});

// THE VIEW
<main id="content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
        <section class="wrapper">
            {{ test }}
            <h1>{{ forecast.temp }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ forecast.description }}</h2>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` will likely cause an error.  Can you create an SSCCE to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: what's the purpose of `event.preventDefault()`? Where is `event` coming from? Can we see your HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a purpose, but I wanted to check it out. Removing it doesn't solve it. I have a button submitting this...

`<form name="getWeatherForm" action="#" ng-submit="getWeather(postData)" class="small-10 large-6 small-centered large-centered columns">`

Comment: Sorry should've specified, what about where you're binding `$scope.test`? Try binding test as an object property, `$scope.obj = { test: 'TEST' }`, then `obj.test = 'NEW'`

Comment: What in your view is not updating? I don't see any usage of `$scope.test` or `$scope.description` in HTML...something like `{{ test }}`

Comment: Exactly. I'll update the code to show the view. Edit: view is now in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working, but the repsonse does not have the assumed properties when the city is not provided or wrong city is provided. So maybe use ng-required, as the code will fail if the postData.city is not set

http://plnkr.co/edit/7F3EUMyAXtAlBR9CGWb0?p=preview

```
       .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.test = 'This is the NEW value';
            $scope.temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
```

Comment: I thought that too, but I got this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

Comment: so this is not the problem. Are you sure the page is not refreshing due to some other javascript... clearing the form again?

Comment: That's what I thought the event.preventDefault() would be for, right?

Comment: It seems to be working! just the response did not have channel property in the response. Remember to put something in the field. The placeholder is not going to be passed in.

Comment: That's great! Thank you! I just copy and pasted your code and it's still not working. I don't see the diff between our code? Can you point it out? What do you mean the reponse didn't have the channel property? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I did... I commented out $scope.temp/description and it still isn't working. I see yours is, but I don't see the difference unfortunately.

Comment: I also realized that if the user enters wrong city name, your code has hidden errors. The result will not have channel from that service

Comment: Problem must be somewhere else. that main directive?

Comment: maybe remove other bits until it starts working, then you find the naughty one

Comment: Thanks a ton. Last question,  what did you change?

Comment: nothing.just copy pasted your code. I did put weather service definition before app module definition. but don't think yours has a problem

Comment: It was stupid. I had a conflict with my app.routes declaring the controller for my view while I also had it delcared within a small scope in the header.

*facepalm*